# how to build opencv framework for osx use stdlibc++

Tags: macos, opencv

I can modify the file of `iOS.cmake` with this code:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libstdc++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden ${no_warn}")
```

But how can I change it for `osx` framework? I cannot find the file named `osx.cmake`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a python script for building the iOS Framework. Find the tutorial here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d5/da3/tutorial_ios_install.html

If you want to do it for macOS, just replace the line `python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios` with `python opencv/platforms/osx/build_framework.py osx`